# Función que recibe un parámetro objeto y retorna un dato específico. Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Estoy aprendiendo Javascript y en el desarrollo de un ejercicio me he quedado bloqueado. El ejercicio me pide que haga una función con JS que recibido el parámetro objeto, retorne el nombre del comercial que más a facturado todo el año.
Los datos sobre los ingresos mensuales generados por los comerciales están guardados en una tabla de objetos, cada elemento de la tabla es un objeto con dos campos, el nombre del comercial y una tabla con la facturación de los doce meses del año de ese comercial.

Primero he creado una tabla para guardar la suma de los ingresos de cada comercial y luego de esa tabla selecciono la facturación más alta, pero no me aparece el nombre del comercial, solo la facturación... y no se como hacer para que me aparezca el nombre.

```js
let comer = [

{nom:"Daniel",
fact:[6899,2713,6827,5805,3058,3679,4094,7581,5867,6901,5116,2392]},

{nom:"Raquel",
fact:[6747,5485,7431,2667,2431,3900,7222,7601,5109,6556,6211,7087]},

{nom:"Eva",
fact:[2831,2645,2242,5586,3124,7396,5556,3268,3186,6632,5319,2263]},

{nom:"Víctor",
fact:[4758,6212,7835,6240,6513,6639,4246,3244,5914,3338,2415,5240]},
];

function sumarIngresos(objeto){
let total= [];
  for (let nom of objeto){
    let subtotal=0; 
    for (let fact of nom.fact){
      subtotal += parseInt(fact)
    }
    total.push(subtotal)
  }
  return total
}
console.log(sumarIngresos(comer));

function maximo(mayor){
  return Math.max.apply (null, mayor);
}
console.log(maximo(sumarIngresos(comer)));
```

Comment: El problema es que en ningún momento estás añadiendo el nombre, cómo se va a mostrar? Declaras `let nom of objeto` en tu bucle pero en realidad `nom` es cada comercial en si mismo, es un objeto `{nom: 'Eva', fact: [...]}` por ejemplo. De este objeto solo accedes a su facturación y eso es lo que metes luego en total y tal cual lo devuelves... si nunca tratas el nombre, nunca va a salir luego. Necesitas trabajar con un objeto `{nom: nom.nom, fact: total}` por ejemplo. Además deberías renombrar el `let nom of objeto` por algo mejor como `let comercial of objeto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dije en mi comentario, el problema es que nunca estás sacando el "nom" de tu primera llamada, con lo cual cuando vas a mirar cual es el mayor ya no lo tienes, se ha perdido. Con las modificaciones que he hecho seguimos llevando el nombre hasta el final, he reutilizado tu código con algunos cambios en nombres de variables y sustituyendo el `Math.max` que solo me devolvía el valor de la facturación por un [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) que me permite "reducir" el array hasta quedarse con un único objeto del mismo.

Además, he añadido `;` en muchas líneas que te faltaban. En JS no es obligatorio usarlos, pero si es *buena práctica* mantener una sintaxis constante durante todo el proceso de programación, o los usas siempre o no los usas. Y la regla general suele ser usarlos puesto que mejoran la legibilidad del código.

```js
// Dado que la variable comer no va a cambiar, la declaramos como const
const comer = [

{nom:"Daniel",
fact:[6899,2713,6827,5805,3058,3679,4094,7581,5867,6901,5116,2392]},

{nom:"Raquel",
fact:[6747,5485,7431,2667,2431,3900,7222,7601,5109,6556,6211,7087]},

{nom:"Eva",
fact:[2831,2645,2242,5586,3124,7396,5556,3268,3186,6632,5319,2263]},

{nom:"Víctor",
fact:[4758,6212,7835,6240,6513,6639,4246,3244,5914,3338,2415,5240]},
];

function sumarIngresos(objeto){
let arrayWithTotals = [];
  for (let comercial of objeto){
    let subtotal=0; 
    for (let fact of comercial.fact){
      subtotal += parseInt(fact);
    }
    arrayWithTotals.push({nom: comercial.nom, total: subtotal});
  }
  return arrayWithTotals;
}

function maximo(comerciales){
  // En vez de math.max, prefiero usar reduce que me permite obtener un único valor del array
  // En este caso, comparo los totales de cada comercial y me quedo con el que sea más grande
  return comerciales.reduce((current, next) => next.total > current.total ? next : current);
}
// De esta manera, cuando imprimes el maximo de todos obtenemos un objeto en vez de una cantidad
// { nom: "Raquel", total: "68447" }
console.log(maximo(sumarIngresos(comer)));
```

Y ya puestos, hay una manera más rápida (corta) de hacerlo usando [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const comer = [
  {
    nom:"Daniel",
    fact:[6899,2713,6827,5805,3058,3679,4094,7581,5867,6901,5116,2392]
  },
  {
    nom:"Raquel",
    fact:[6747,5485,7431,2667,2431,3900,7222,7601,5109,6556,6211,7087]
  },
  {
    nom:"Eva",
    fact:[2831,2645,2242,5586,3124,7396,5556,3268,3186,6632,5319,2263]
  },
  {
    nom:"Víctor",
    fact:[4758,6212,7835,6240,6513,6639,4246,3244,5914,3338,2415,5240]
  }
];

function getBestSalesman(salesmen) {
  return salesmen
  .map((p) => {
      // aquí es necesario poner corchetes porque vamos a modificar un valor del objeto
      // pero no queremos devolver ese valor!
      p.fact = p.fact.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
      // Devolvemos la persona entera, no solo su facturación
      return p;
    }
  ).reduce((a, b) => a.fact > b.fact ? a:b);
}

console.log(getBestSalesman(comer));
```

Comment: Gracias!, lo he entendido perfectamente. Me queda mucho camino por recorrer en el mundo de JavaScript.